# Can I get away with using Big Query instead of datastore?

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-datastore, datastore

I am creating an online competition. All the members on the platform can form teams. All team scoring is based on transactional data that is in Big Query already. This data is populated by some chron job.

The problem? My Big Query transactional data is updated once a day. With the member and team data sitting in datastore, I have to run a job to get all the transactional data from Big Query, and then update every entity in my DataStore (Propagation).

This feels extremely expensive. I would prefer to get away with putting my Team and Member data in Big Query. Then call GetScore() that will retrieve everything with out the need of propagation to DataStore. Can I do this? I know Big Query shouldn't be used as a transactional database, but only member creation/updation, and team creation/updation, as well as team invites and team accept will occur in BigQuery. Is this little enough transaction operations to just go ahead and use Big Query for everything?

All types involved. Team and Members are currently in Datastore, Score is in BigQuery:

```golang
type Member struct {
    PhoneNum string `json:"phoneNum"`
    Teams []string `json:"teams"`
    Password string `json:"password"`
}

type Team struct {
    TeamName string `json:"teamName"`
    ScoreId string `json:"scoreId"`
    InviteCode string `json:"inviteCode"`
}

type Score struct {
    ScoreId string `json:"scoreId"`
    Score1 float64 `json:"score1"` [these scores are calculated in the BigQuery]
    Score2 float64 `json:"score2"`
    Score3 float64 `json:"score3"`
}
```

If we use the Teams and Members in BigQuery, then foreign keys can be used for that "Propagation process"

Thank you so much for taking the time to answer my question.

Comment: Bigquery should not be used as database for applications where you need to serve data immediately to the frontend. Because Bigquery is slower compared to SQL databases and it charges on amount of data processed per query. So running lots of heavy queries frequently can blow up your bill

Comment: @dishantmakwana, Thank you, I never thought about the costs on this yet. I guess it is a no brainer. Immediate live rapid querying in datastore.

Reporting bulk in big query.

Answer (score 0):

Posting this as a Community Wiki answer, as part of it was based in the comments.

Using BigQuery is not the best option for you to store data as use it as database for your application, mainly because, considering the fact that you need the data to be loaded in the frontend of the application as soon as possible, BigQuery is not fast as you may need. For this reason, using a specific application for the database would be the best option.

Adding to that, an alternative you might want to take a look at for database application is Firestore in native mode. As your application works basically with texts and small amounts of data, Firestore might help you, as Firestore is organized in documents of small size. Besides that, while both Datastore and Firestore has the same free quotas - check quotas and prices [here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/pricing) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/pricing) - their costs are different and one might make more sense the other for you.